# How to replace timestamp of messages received on an rsyslog server with a local timestamp?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I have a router that forwards its logs to an rsyslog server and I'd like to configure the rsyslog server to replace the timestamp with a local timestamp. The message format looks like this:

```
Jan  1 00:00:47 192.168.1.254 kernel: br0: port 1(eth0) entered forwarding state
```

What's the best way to do this for all messages from this router (192.168.1.254)?

Comment: this may helps https://superuser.com/questions/164339/timezone-conversion-by-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to write a template that is a copy of the template you are already using, and change the `timestamp` property to the `timegenerated` property. Eg, assuming you are writing to a file and using the default `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` [template](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html), then you can create `myFileFormat`, test for the ip address and put in your matching rules. In legacy format the rule uses the log filename followed by `;` and the name of the template:

```
template(name="myFileFormat" type="string" string="%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp% %msg:::drop-last-lf%\n") 
if $fromhost-ip == "192.168.1.254" then {
   *.* /my/logfile;myFileFormat
   stop
}
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks. It's also clicked for me now how templates work.